# Axios sending url with params as string not object

Tags: axios

i need to take url with params example:

`https://domain.pl/ptpdf-gen?selected_posts=4871&advisor=magda,wojciech`

But axios response is an object like:

`{"https://domain.pl/ptpdf-gen?selected_posts":"4871","advisor":"magda,wojciech"}`

How to send url as string via axios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i made the url split like this, using URLSearchParams:

```
const currHref = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('selected_posts');
const myParam2 = urlParams.get('advisor');
```

Then with axios.post i can send params:

```
axios.post("http://domain.pl/create", {myParam, myParam2})
```

On server i did handle params like:

```
const state = req.body;
const stateValues = Object.values(state);
```

And then i can concat url with stateValues[0] and stateValues[1];

```
let linkUrl = "https://domain.pl/ptpdf-gen?selected_posts=" + stateValues[0] + "&advisor=" + stateValues[1];
```

Works.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selected = 4871
var advisor = ["magda","wojciech"]
axios.post('https://domain.pl/ptpdf-gen', {selected, advisor })
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your answer. Provide only a solution doesn't add value and mark for low quality posts.

Answer (score 0):

Optionally the request above could also be done as

```js
axios.get('/user', {
    params: {
      selected_posts: 4871
      advisor: ["magda", "Wojciech"]
    },
    paramsSerializer: params => {
      return qs.stringify(params)
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
     // always executed
  });
```

The qs is an external library,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs